# Where do places like Xandar and the Kree empire fit within the Nine Realms from Thor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, thor-the-dark-world

I have got a confusion regarding where the places mentioned in Guardians of the Galaxy can fit within the 9 realms described in Thor.

Is the entire universe contained within the 9 realms, or are places like Xandar and Knowhere situated somewhere outside the tree of Yggdrasil?

Comment: see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44857/how-are-the-nine-realms-situated-in-space

Comment: @Daft the "second" answer depends on the viewer's settings. To eliminate ambiguity, I recommend referring to the answer by the username, or link directly to it (grab the link from the "share" button next to it).

Comment: So,According to the links provided in the comments what we can infer is that the realms other than the midgard are the dwelling places of cosmic  entities (consisting of Gods,hells where dead people who commit sins end up etc...).They are the places or dimensions which are not easily accessible by common living beings (People of midgard).So it is midgard that has got different planetary systems,galaxies etc.Hence Xandar,Kree empire are other planets within midgard.Please correct me if my inference is wrong.

Comment: @phantom42 good idea...

Comment: The [answer found here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/44868/20393) covers this pretty well.