# Is it possible that Hulk flew to Asgard?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

Mark Ruffalo (who plays Hulk) has informed us that he will be starring in the next *Thor: Ragnarok*.

I want to know if it's possible that, when Hulk is in the quinjet at the end of *Age of Ultron*, he could have ended up in Asgard to then appear in the film?

Comment: Typically, questions about the plot of upcoming movies are discouraged, and this is pretty much entirely going to be opinion-based.  That said, the answer is almost certainly, "No."

Comment: I don't believe Hulk nor the aircraft are capable of realm-traveling flight, so I doubt he's going anywhere off-planet without Thor's help (as Jane Foster did in Thor 2).  [This interview](http://screenrant.com/hulk-thor-3-explained/) provides some details in addition to speculation on the film.

Comment: Quinjet gets him to Sacar. Perhaps he has just left our atmosphere when he comes across a wormhole?

Comment: This has now been answered: [How did Hulk and his Quinjet end up on Sakaar?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/173435/23745)

Answer (score 6):

Doubtful.

There are 4 ways to get from Earth to Asgard, that we've seen so far:

1. The shortcuts between realms.  We see Loki use one of these in *Thor: The Dark World*.  Since this relies on the presence of the Rainbow Bridge material, it's unlikely that Hulk would use this.  He'd need to either purposefully or accidentally use Rainbow Bridge material on Earth.  Since we don't know that Bruce Banner is knowledgeable on [Asgardian intergalactic travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10181/1027), it seems unlikely he'd purposefully use the stuff.  And since we've never seen natural deposits of Rainbow Bridge material on Earth, it's unlikely he'd stumble upon some.
2. Regular intergalactic technology, from *Guardians of the Galaxy*.  Peter Quill was taken by the Ravagers from Earth to [the galaxy](http://www.tor.com/2014/08/08/joss-whedon-marvel-movies-continuity-guardians-of-the-galaxy/) we see in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, which indicates intergalactic travel via technology is available to the Ravagers.  But we've seen no indication that Bruce Banner has knowledge or access to this technology.
3. The Bifrost, from the Thor films.  This would be the likely way for him to get from Earth to Asgard, assuming that's where he is in *Thor: Ragnarok*.  It's the only method he's known to have access to, but it's not something that meets the specifications of the question, as it's not something the Hulk would just achieve by flying around in the jet.
4. [Dark Energy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39910/1027), which is another Asgardian technology/magic.  This has the same issues as #1, as Banner likely lacks the knowledge and technology available to Odin. (thanks CBredlow)

It's worth mentioning that Joss Whedon [originally wanted](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/What-Joss-Whedon-Originally-Wanted-Do-With-Hulk-Avengers-2-71321.html) to include a shot in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* showing Hulk flying off into the upper atmosphere, but was forbidden from doing this.  This means that at the time of *Age of Ultron*, Marvel did not want to show the Hulk just flying off-world, which suggests that this is not going to be how Hulk would get to another realm in *Thor: Ragnarok*.

Comment: There's also Dark Energy, whatever that is.  It's mentioned in Avengers Assemble "I wonder how much Dark Energy Odin needed to conjure to send you here"